# VBA Copy Sheet to End of Workbook (with Hidden Worksheets)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a sheet and add it to the end of all current sheets (regardless of whether the sheets are hidden).

```
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = "copied sheet!"
```

This works fine, except, when there are hidden sheets, the new sheet is only inserted after the last visible worksheet, so the `name` command renames the wrong sheet.

I have tried variations of the following to get a reference to the newly copied `WorkSheet` but none were successful and/or valid code.

```
Dim test As Worksheet
Set test = Sheets(1).Copy(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
test.Name = "copied sheet!"
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim test As Worksheet
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set test = ActiveSheet
    test.Name = "copied sheet!"
End Sub
```

Looking back at this, a better approach would be

```
Set test = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

As correctly mentioned in the comments below, there are lot of things that needs to be considered when copying and renaming a sheet. Would recommend checking the other answers as well.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't realize the newly copied sheet is activated immediately after being copied.. :)  edit - it's not pretty but it will work for what I need.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work if you're using Application.ScreenUpdating = False to hide flickering.

Comment: If original sheet is hidden and you copy that sheet, the new sheet is also hidden. Thus you code fails to work.

Comment: Just in case: If source sheet is `.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden`, it can not be copied! If source sheet is `.Visible = xlSheetHidden`, then it can be copied, but the new sheet is NOT the Activesheet.

Comment: comments are right: this solution fails in stated cases: they should be included in the solution as caveats
While @dra_red code looks promising as a general solution

Answer (score 9):

Make the source sheet visible before copying. Then copy the sheet so that the copy also stays visible. The copy will then be the active sheet. If you want, hide the source sheet again.

Comment: I confirm, this is the "cleaner" way. It works also with ScreenUpdating=False.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while copying a sheet to another workbook. I prefer to avoid using 'activesheet' though as it has caused me issues in the past. Hence I wrote a function to perform this inline with my needs. I add it here for those who arrive via google as I did:

The main issue here is that copying a visible sheet to the last index position results in Excel repositioning the sheet to the end of the visible sheets. Hence copying the sheet to the position after the last visible sheet sorts this issue. Even if you are copying hidden sheets.

```
Function Copy_WS_to_NewWB(WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet) As Worksheet
    'Creates a copy of the specified worksheet in the specified workbook
    '   Accomodates the fact that there may be hidden sheets in the workbook
    
    Dim WSInd As Integer: WSInd = 1
    Dim CWS As Worksheet
    
    'Determine the index of the last visible worksheet
    For Each CWS In WB.Worksheets
        If CWS.Visible Then If CWS.Index > WSInd Then WSInd = CWS.Index
    Next CWS
    
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Worksheets(WSInd)
    Set Copy_WS_to_NewWB = WB.Worksheets(WSInd + 1)

End Function
```

To use this function for the original question (ie in the same workbook) could be done with something like...

```
Set test = Copy_WS_to_NewWB(Workbooks(1), Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1))
test.name = "test sheet name"
```

---

EDIT 04/11/2020 from –user3598756
Adding a slight refactoring of the above code

```
Function CopySheetToWorkBook(targetWb As Workbook, shToBeCopied As Worksheet, copiedSh As Worksheet) As Boolean
    'Creates a copy of the specified worksheet in the specified workbook
    '   Accomodates the fact that there may be hidden sheets in the workbook

    Dim lastVisibleShIndex As Long
    Dim iSh As Long

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    
    With targetWb
        'Determine the index of the last visible worksheet
        For iSh = .Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Sheets(iSh).Visible Then
                lastVisibleShIndex = iSh
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    
        shToBeCopied.Copy after:=.Sheets(lastVisibleShIndex)
        Set copiedSh = .Sheets(lastVisibleShIndex + 1)
    End With
    
    CopySheetToWorkBook = True
    Exit Function
    
SafeExit:
    
End Function
```

other than using different (more descriptive?) variable names, the refactoring manily deals with:

1. turning the Function type into a `Boolean
   while including returned (copied) worksheet within function parameters list
   this, to let the calling Sub hande possible errors, like

   ```
    Dim WB as Workbook: Set WB = ThisWorkbook ' as an example
    Dim sh as Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet ' as an example
    Dim copiedSh as Worksheet
    If CopySheetToWorkBook(WB, sh, copiedSh) Then
        ' go on with your copiedSh sheet
    Else
        Msgbox "Error while trying to copy '" & sh.Name & "'" & vbcrlf & err.Description
    End If
   ```
2. having the For - Next loop stepping from last sheet index backwards and exiting at first visible sheet occurence, since we're after the "last" visible one

Comment: Hi @dra_red: really well though solution. This should be the accepted one since it does overcome all those possible issues that have been detected in Siddharth Rout's one comments
I hope you don't mind I edited your solution adding a possible refactoring: of course you can edit them back and/or edit your solution with some of mine suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following code based on @Siddharth Rout's code, you rename the just copied sheet, no matter, if it is activated or not.

```
Sub Sample()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "copied sheet!"

End Sub
```

Comment: When there are hidden worksheets at the end of the worksheet queue, the code you've supplied renames the last hidden worksheet, *not* the new worksheet created from the copy operation.

Comment: of course you should always unhide/hide worksheets when you need to. So first unhide `your code` hide again.

Comment: No, you would have to unhide every sheet in the destination workbook, which is unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code to the beginning:**

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With ThisWorkbook
      Dim ws As Worksheet
       For Each ws In Worksheets: ws.Visible = True: Next ws
     End With
```

**Add this code to the end:**

```
    With ThisWorkbook
     Dim ws As Worksheet
      For Each ws In Worksheets: ws.Visible = False: Next ws
    End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**Adjust Code at the end if you want more than the first sheet to be active and visible. Such as the following:**

```
     Dim ws As Worksheet
      For Each ws In Worksheets
       If ws.Name = "_DataRecords" Then

         Else: ws.Visible = False
       End If
      Next ws
```

**To ensure the new sheet is the one renamed, adjust your code similar to the following:**

```
     Sheets(Me.cmbxSheetCopy.value).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
     Sheets(Me.cmbxSheetCopy.value & " (2)").Select
     Sheets(Me.cmbxSheetCopy.value & " (2)").Name = txtbxNewSheetName.value
```

This code is from my user form that allows me to copy a particular sheet (chosen from a dropdown box) with the formatting and formula's that I want to a new sheet and then rename new sheet with the user Input. Note that every time a sheet is copied it is automatically given the old sheet name with the designation of " (2)". Example "OldSheet" becomes "OldSheet (2)" after the copy and before the renaming. So you must select the Copied sheet with the programs naming before renaming.

Comment: This would wreck whatever sheets the user wanted hidden or visible.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to copy a sheet named "mySheet" and use .Copy After:=, Excel first names the copied sheet exactly the same and simply adds ' (2)' so that its final name is "mySheet (2)".

Hidden or Not, doesn't matter. It rocks with 2 lines of code, adding the copied sheet at the end of the Workbook!!!

**Example:**

```
Sheets("mySheet").Copy After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
Sheets("mySheet (2)").name = "TheNameYouWant"
```

Simple no!

Answer (score 0):

TRY This if your first sheet is not visible

`Sheets(1).Visible = True Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = "copied sheet!" Sheets(1).Visible = False`

Comment: This code fails when there is another sheet with 'Visible' attribute equal to 'xlSheetHidden' or 'xlSheetVeryHidden' at the end of the queue as mentioned earlier here. Tested with a set of 5 sheets, the 4th and 5th in the queue with attribute 'Visible' = 'xlSheetHidden' or 'xlSheetVeryHidden' as per OP statement. Visually, the copied sheet moved to the end of the queue in the VBE's Project Explorer window. However, it is accessed with index 4, that is, the 4th and last visible, in a total of 6. And the sheet that was renamed was the last one, with the property 'Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden'.

Answer (score -3):

**Answer :** I found this and wants to share it with you.

```
Sub Copier4()
   Dim x As Integer

   For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
      'Loop through each of the sheets in the workbook
      'by using x as the sheet index number.
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(x).Copy _
         After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
         'Puts all copies after the last existing sheet.
   Next
End Sub
```

But the question, can we use it with following code to rename the sheets, if yes, how can we do so?

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A10")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
Next MyCell
End Sub
```