# Setting a worksheet to another worksheet vba

Tags: excel, vba, object, spreadsheet

Been coding vba for a while now and never found a satisfactory answer to this fairly simple problem.

Is it possible to set a sheet in my current workbook to a sheet variable returned by a function. Here is my code:

```
Sub script()

    Dim isin As Range
    Set isin = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All data points") = allDataPoints(isin)

End Sub
```

The "allDataPoints" function takes in range and returns a worksheet. I get the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

I know there are ways around it like copying all cells on a sheet or setting a range of 10,000 rows equal to a range on a new sheet, but surely there is a more intuitive way of setting a sheet to be the same as another sheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Copy Sheet to End of Workbook (with Hidden Worksheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990465/vba-copy-sheet-to-end-of-workbook-with-hidden-worksheets)

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All data points")` is not something you can assign a new value to. I would look into recreating the sheet by creating a copy of the one you're returning in your function.

Comment: Not sure what you're after.  You have `Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")` and you just want that copied to `All data points`?  You say `allDataPoints` returns a worksheet - how does it do that? From the little code you've given I'd say it can only sensibly return the parent of the range you pass to it, so in this case it returns `Sheet1`?  Can we see the code for `allDataPoints` - at the moment it looks like a convoluted way to copy a range from one sheet to another.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I could give you the code for the allDataPoints function but it really doesn't help. The question is really, can you set a sheet in your current workbook to another sheet in another workbook. The same way you could set a range equal to another range. Doesn't look like you can though without actually copying cell values on a worksheet.

Comment: Can you post the `allDataPoints` function?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All data points")` is really an object (a `Worksheet`). So if your function `allDataPoints` returns a `Worksheet` object, then use `Set ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All data points") = allDataPoints(isin)` and it should work.